# Storing result set for later fetch

Tags: java, sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle

I have some queries that run for a quite long (20-30 minutes). If a lot of queries are started simultaneously, connection pool is drained quickly.

Is it possible to wrap the long-running query into a statement (procedure) that will store the result of a generic query into a temp table, terminanting the connection, and fetchin (polling) the results later on demand?

**EDIT:** queries and data stuctures are optimized, and tips like 'check your indices and execution plan' don't work for me. I'm looking for a way to store [maybe a] byte presentation of a generic result set, for later retreive.

Comment: You could also post your query, I bet some expert here could speed it up a bit.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to optimize one or two queries.

Comment: Can you increase the number of connections?

Comment: @jonearles Connection pool capacity ATM is 50. I can increase it, but given that the most of connections are idle, I'd prefer making polling a result set instead of waiting for a quiry to complete.

Comment: How are these queries being executed?  Through an application you can't control, or just by you?  If these are just queries you execute, JOTN's "create table as select" solution should work.

Comment: I'm calling them from a Java application through JDBC. On the JOTN's solution -- ain't it too expensive to create a new table per each query result?

Comment: The amount of time to create a table is negligible compared to the amount of time required to convert rows into and out of another format.  Always keep your data in a relational format if possible.  (Although there are issues with creating and dropping lots of tables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most generic approach in Oracle I can think of is creating a stored procedure that will convert a result set into XML, and store it as CLOB XMLType in a table with the results of your long-running queries.

You can find more on generation XMLs from a generic result sets [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_format_output_html_xml.htm).

```
SQL> select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select employee_id, first_name,
  2  last_name, phone_number from employees where rownum < 6') xml
  3  from dual
```

Comment: Why? You think, creating a new table per each result set structure you want to store is better?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, 20-30 minutes is an *extremely* long time for a query - are you sure you aren't missing any indexes for the query? Do check your execution plan - you could get a huge performance gain from a well-placed index.

In MySQL, you could do

```
INSERT INTO `cached_result_table` (
    SELECT your_query_here
)
```

(of course, `cached_result_table` needs to have the exact same column structure as your `SELECT` returns, otherwise you'll get an error).

Then, you could query these cached results (instead of the original tables), and only run the above query from time to time - to update the cached_result_table.

Of course, the query will need to run at least once initially, which will take the 20-30 minutes you mentioned. I suggest to pre-populate the cached table before the data are requested, and keep some locking mechanism to prevent the update query to run several times simultaneously. Pseudocode:

```
init:
insert select your_big_query

work:
if your_big_query cached table is empty or nearing expiration:
  refresh in the background:
     check flag to see if there's another "refresh" process running
     if yes
       end // don't run two your_big_queries at the same time
     else 
       set flag
       re-run your_big_query, save to cached table
       clear flag
serve data to clients always from cached table
```

Comment: "...Btw 20-30 minutes is a rather long time - are you sure you aren't missing any indexes for the query?..." - +1 just for this.

Comment: @duffymo: I've moved this notice to the beginning. It's common sense, but gets overlooked sometimes.

Comment: @Piskvor Thx for the tips! 1. All the queries are optmized (the amount of data end complixity is just too huge (-> client usage statistics of a telco provider) - that's where 20-30 minutes come from). 2. Is there any possibility to generalize your approach, so that I won't have to create a table per query, but rather store byte presentation of a result set, or smth like that.

Comment: @Dave: Thought so - telcos tend to generate a humongous amount of data. As for storing the resultset, AFAIK you'd have to do that sort of caching outside the database - MySQL won't help you much in such case.

Comment: We're using Oracle in production. That was nasty to add mysql tag - I just wanted to have as much expertise as possible :) Caching of the result set is not a primarily aim I'm trying to achieve. What I'm trying to do is to release the blocked client socket that waits for the queury to complete, and get the computd resul set later, on demand (caching would be just an additional cool option). So far, solution proposed by @Vasil Remeniuk looks the most interesting for me.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do that in Oracle is "CREATE TABLE sometempname AS SELECT...".  That will create a new table using the result columns from the select.

Comment: Will the created table be populated with the data from the result set?

Comment: Yes, it will contain the data.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are requesting.

Currently you have 50 database sessions. Say you get 40 running long-running queries, that leaves 10 to service the rest.

What you seem to be asking for is, you want those 40 queries asynchronously (running in the background) not clogging up the connection pool of 50. The question is, do you want those 40 running concurrently with (potentially) another 50 queries from the connection pool, or do you want them queued up in some way ?

Queuing can be done (look into DBMS_SCHEDULER and DBMS_JOB). But you will need to deliver those results into some other table and know how to deliver that result set. The old fashioned way is simply to generate reports on request that get delivered to a directory on a shared drive or by email. Could be PDF or CSV or Excel.

If you want the 40 running concurrently alongside the 50 'connection pool' settings, then you may be best off setting up a separate connection pool for the long-running queries.

You can look into Resource Manager for terminating calls that take too long or too many resources. That way the quickie pool can't get bogged down in long running requests.

Comment: I have a pool of 50 connections in JDBC - driver that I use to connect to the database from Java. JDBC creates a VM thread per each database connection (behind the scenes, connection is a blocking client socket), and what I'm trying to achieve is to work with long-running queries in a fire-and-forget mode, releaseing the thread/connection right after pushing the queue to the database, and fetching the result set later.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your problem is that the client is max'ed out at 50 connections but the database still has capacity.